# bilinear form and positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bilinear-form

Let $B$ a symmetric bilinear form on an $n$ dimensional vector space $E$ with signature $(n-1,1)$. Then there exists a hyperplane $H$ in $E$ in which $B$ is positive definite. How to prove this?  Is it true that $B$ has signature  $(n-1,1)$ implies the matrix corresponding to $B$ in some fixed basis of $E$ has $n-1$ positive eigenvalues and one negative eigen value. In particular the matrix corresponding to $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Which definition of signature do you use?

Comment: I don't know what exactly signature of a bilinear form means. Can you please explain ?

Comment: The condition on eigenvalues you use in your question is one of the possible definitions of signature. Signature $(n-1,1)$ on a space of dimension $n$ implies that the form is non-degnerate and hence its matrix with respect to any basis is invertible.

Comment: How to prove the existence of a hyperplane H in E such that B restricted to H is positive definite if the bilinear form B has signature (n-1,1)?

Comment: Take the sum of the eigenspaces corresponding to positive eigenvalues.